# Codeigniter REST API, difference between PUT and POST

Tags: codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-restserver

I am making an API for my site using Philip Sturgeon's REST server and i am in a little dilemma. I am not shure which action to use for edit and which for create. POST or PUT?

Comment: This post explains it very well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/630475/1932551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *POST* method is usually used for *create* operations,
and the *PUT* is used for *edit/update* operations.

Answer (score 0):

Put methods are Idempotent whereas Post methods are non-Idempotent.
means put are safely repeatable and post are not safely repeatable