# Postman is getting redirected for unknown reason and route not working/ Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, postman

I can see that postman is being redirected for some reason. I have just started using postman so not sure what a normal request would look like.  When I make the following request;

```
POST https://development.example.com/Api/Register
form-data
KEY name
VALUE Thomas
KEY _method
VALUE PUT
```

For some reason it returns my top page of my website.  When I look at the apache2 log file, I can see:

```
124.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [27/Feb/2022:09:08:36 +0000] "POST /Api/Register HTTP/1.1" 303 5724 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4"

124.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [27/Feb/2022:09:08:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8185 "https://development.example.com/Api/Register" "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4"
```

When I access it through a web browser like chrome (and I cannot submit any values of course), I get below which is expected;

```
 {
   "status": 500,
   "message": {
       "name": "The name field is required",
       "email": "The email field is required",
       "password": "The password field is required.",
       "password_confirmation": "The password_confirmation field is required."
   },
   "error": true,
   "data": []
}
```

What am I doing wrong with POSTMAN please?

My `Users` controller is;

```
public function userRegister(){
    $user = new UserEntity($this->request->getPost());
    $user->startActivation();
    if ($this->UserModel->insert($user)){
        $this->sendActivationEmail($user);
        $response =[
            'status'    => 200,
            'message'   => 'User registed.  Check email to activate account.',
            'error'     => false,
            'data'      => []
        ];
    } else {
        $response =[
            'status'    => 500,
            'message'   => $this->UserModel->errors(),
            'error'     => true,
            'data'      => []
        ];
    }
    return $this->respondCreated($response);
}
```

What is also puzzling is that the route is NOT accessible via;

My routes file is;

```
$routes->group('Api', ["namespace" => 'App\Controllers\Api\v1'] , function($routes){
    $routes->post('Register', 'Users::userRegister');
});

https://development.example.com/Api/Register
Error;  Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Api\Register::index

https://development.example.com/Api/v1/Users/userRegister 
This will work and give correct error like way above.
```

Comment: I have removed all routes except the $routes->group('Api',...   The error I get back in postman is  "title": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException", "type": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException", "code": 404, "message": "Controller or its method is not found: \\App\\Controllers\\Home::index", "file":

Comment: `https://development.example.com/Api/v1/Users/userRegister` How come this route has `v1` the API version number?

Comment: the actual namespace is development.example.com/Api/v1/Users/userRegister but the route is Api/Register. Yes, v1 is the version number

Comment: Yet `https://development.example.com/Api/Register` has no API version number?

Comment: Oh?  Am I doing the routes incorrectly?

Comment: I think you're confusing [PHP Namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) with URL paths. These can't be used interchangeably. They are completely different concepts. Please read [Codeigniter 4 Grouping Routes](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#grouping-routes)

Comment: $routes->group('Api', ["namespace" => 'App\Controllers\Api\V1'] , function($routes){
    $routes->post('Register', 'Users::userRegister');
});
I cannot see a problem with this.  The documentation is the same as far as I can see.

Comment: `https://development.example.com/Api/v1/Users/userRegister ` Can you share the route definition corresponding to this URL path, please?

Comment: $routes->group('Api', ["namespace" => 'App\Controllers\Api\V1'] , function($routes){ $routes->post('Register', 'Users::userRegister'); });   I thought this is the route definition.  The controller is /App/Controllers/Api/V1/Users and method registerUser().  The URL is then /Api/Register. Is that not what this group route says?  Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242449/discussion-between-spreaderman-and-steven7mwesigwa).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're essentially making a `PUT` request in [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)  (`_method PUT`), yet your route definition in the file **app/Config/Routes.php** *only* responds to `POST` requests (`$routes->post('Register', 'Users::userRegister');`).

To fix this, remove the `_method` POST request parameter from Postman:

```sh
POST https://development.example.com/Api/Register
form-data
KEY name
VALUE Thomas
```

##### Addendum

*The seemingly `POST` Postman request in your question is being **implicitly interpreted** as a `PUT` request by the Codeigniter framework because of **HTTP Method Spoofing***.

[HTTP Method Spoofing](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/methodspoofing.html#http-method-spoofing)

> When working with HTML forms you can only use GET or POST HTTP verbs.
> In most cases, this is just fine. However, to support REST-ful routing
> you need to support other, more correct, verbs, like DELETE or PUT.
> Since the browsers don’t support this, CodeIgniter provides you with a
> way to spoof the method that is being used. This allows you to make a
> POST request, but tell the application that it should be treated as a
> different request type.
>
> To spoof the method, a hidden input is added to the form with the name
> of `_method`. It’s value is the HTTP verb that you want the request to
> be:
>
> ```php
>    <form action="" method="post">
>        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
>    </form>
> ```

> This form is converted into a PUT request and is a true PUT request as
> far as the routing and the IncomingRequest class are concerned.
>
> The form that you are using must be a POST request. GET requests
> cannot be spoofed.

Comment: I don't think so.  The POST method is usually used for create operations,
and the PUT is used for edit/update operations. So post should work.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096704/codeigniter-rest-api-difference-between-put-and-post. Anyway, I tried with PUT and same thing.  /register should be a POST

Comment: Have also tried this route:  $routes->post('register', 'App\Controllers\Api\V1\Users::userRegister');  And it still goes for my Home::index with this error { "title": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException", "type": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException", "code": 404, "message": "Controller or its method is not found: \\App\\Controllers\\Home::index", "file":

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. Please, read it again. I **never** suggested that you change the HTTP verb in Postman. I *only* pointed out that the seemingly `POST` Postman request in your question is being **implicitly interpreted** as a `PUT` request by the Codeigniter framework because of **HTTP Method Spoofing**.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  I have tried POST https://development.motorvessel.com/register KEY name VALUE Thomas and route like this $routes->post('register', 'App\Controllers\Api\V1\Users::userRegister'); but same error.  How is CI implicitly interpreting this as PUT?

Comment: @spreaderman The implicit interpretation **only** happens if you have a `_method` request parameter in your `POST` request body. I think this is clear enough.

Comment: ok, so I am not using  _method to spoof.